# Where are Chrome/Chromium preferences stored? (to force chrome uniformity in fonts)

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, configuration, chromium, settings

I want to force Chrome fonts to be consistent on every site I visit.  The Chrome preferences don't affect this at all.

I found [this link](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=05ffb701b2d72050&hl=en) which states which webkit settings to edit to accomplish this, but where are the preferences stored on linux?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Chrome/chromium keeps it's settings hidden in the `.config` directory in `home`. You can unhide it by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> in nautilus file manager.

The file you're looking for is in:

**google chrome:**

> ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences

**chromium:**

> ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences

Comment: Thank you for the very concise answer.  Sadly, changing these preferences did not help at all.  They change headings and titles on things like the Chrome console (ctrl+shift+j) but not much else.  I think if I replace the Arial font on my machine with something nice it should do the trick.

Comment: For Chromium 100.0.4896.88 flatpak on linux, I found the preferences in: `~/.var/app/org.chromium.Chromium/config/chromium/Profile 1/Preferences`